# Como salvar uma série de planilhas xls em csv usando o R?

Tags: r

Tenho 198 planilhas todas em Excel (formato xls) e preciso passá-las para o formato .csv de forma que possa trabalhar com elas no R. Essas planilhas estão salvas dentro de uma pasta no meu computador todas elas em formato .xls

Depois de transformá-las para .csv preciso unir todas elas de forma a obter uma tabela de similaridade, contendo nas linhas as minhas áreas de estudo e nas colunas as minhas espécies de plantas, preenchendo com dados de abundância de espécies para cada área amostrada. Além da similaridade, preciso calcular parâmetros que estão estruturando minhas comunidades de plantas como, por exemplo, frequência, densidade e dominância.

Assim sendo, de início, gostaria de ter um comando no R onde ele possa transformar automaticamente minhas tabelas .xls em .csv para que possa iniciar minha jornada, uma vez que demorarei muito tempo para salvar uma por uma...

Alguém pode me responder como faço isso utilizando o R?

Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 4):

Se todas essas planilhas estiverem em uma única pasta, você poderá usar algo do tipo. Estou imaginando que todas as planilhas possuem o mesmo formato.

```
plans <- list.files("caminho/da/pasta", full.names = T)
bases <- plyr::ldply(plans, readxl::read_excel)
```

Se elas não possírem e você ainda quiser salvar como `csv` para trabalhar mais fácil no R, você pode fazer algo assim:

```
plans <- list.files("caminho/da/pasta", full.names = T)
plyr::l_ply(plans, function(p){
    b <- readxl::read_excel(p)
    write.csv2(b, file = gsub("xls", "csv", p))
})
```

Comment: Daniel, obrigado pela resposta! Metade dessas planilhas estão em uma pasta e outra metade em outra pasta. Todos os arquivos estão no formato .xls e quero transformá-los em .csv. Depois de transformar todas as minhas planilhas em .csv quero juntá-las para que possa trabalhar com os dados obtendo dados de frequência, densidade, dominância e abundância das espécies, permitindo entender o funcionamento das comunidades que estou trabalhando.

Comment: Daniel, muito obrigado. Consegui fazer do jeito que você colocou na segunda opção. Instalei readxl e deu tudo certo. Agora vou tentar trabalhar com esses dados.

Comment: Legal! Qualquer coisa estamos à disposição! Tente entender o que cada linha do código faz, isso vai ajudá-lo a prosseguir a análise.

Answer (score 3):

Não é necessário converter uma planilha do excel (assumindo que isto signifique arquivos com extensão .xls ou .xlsx) em .csv para trabalhar com ela no R. Instale o pacote `xlsx` e suas dependências para poder rodar o comando

```
library(xlsx)
dados <- read.xlsx(file="planilha.xlsx", sheetIndex=1)
```

Neste exemplo, eu importei apenas a primeira planilha presente no arquivo `planilha.xlsx`. Basta que tu adapte este código para as tuas necessidades.

Comment: acho melhor usar o pacote `readxl` https://github.com/hadley/readxl Ele não depende do `rJava` que geralmente causa bastante problema

Comment: Concordo com o Daniel, o `readxl` é muito mais simples e tem a assinatura do Hadley: faz só uma coisa, e faz muito bem.